# Why are my 2 sites on the same server (randomly?) switching PHP versions with PHP-FPM

Tags: php, apache2

My issue is as follows:

1 server running Debian 11 (though I've tested with 9 and 10 and they both show the same behaviour) with 2 websites both configured to run with php-fpm & apache. Each site has a single index.php file and the contents of those files is `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`. 1 site has been set to run php8.0 and the other php8.1, this represents a real world situation that I'm dealing with. This has been set up by including an apache config file into my main apache config file for each site with the contents:

```
<IfModule proxy_fcgi_module>
# Enable http authorization headers
<IfModule setenvif_module>
SetEnvIfNoCase ^Authorization$ "(.+)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1
</IfModule>

<FilesMatch ".+\.ph(ar|p|tml)$">
    <If "-f %{REQUEST_FILENAME}">
        SetHandler "proxy:unix:/run/php/php8.0-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost"
    </If>
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch ".+\.(phps|inc)$">
    # Deny access to raw php sources by default
    # To re-enable it's recommended to enable access to the files
    # only in specific virtual host or directory
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>
# Deny access to files without filename (e.g. '.php')
<FilesMatch "^\.ph(ar|p|ps|tml)$">
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>
```

The config file for php8.1 then uses the php8.1-fpm.sock. ps aux shows the following:

```
root      114787  0.0  0.3 222780 27312 ?        Ss   17:10   0:00 php-fpm: master process (/etc/php/8.0/fpm/php-fpm.conf)
www-data  114788  0.0  0.5 247140 48664 ?        S    17:10   0:03 php-fpm: pool www
www-data  114789  0.0  0.5 247128 48592 ?        S    17:10   0:03 php-fpm: pool www
www-data  114790  0.0  0.6 247136 48748 ?        S    17:10   0:03 php-fpm: pool www
www-data  114791  0.0  0.5 247128 48676 ?        S    17:10   0:05 php-fpm: pool www
www-data  114792  0.0  0.5 247132 48548 ?        S    17:10   0:04 php-fpm: pool www
root      114802  0.0  0.3 227196 28120 ?        Ss   17:10   0:00 php-fpm: master process (/etc/php/8.1/fpm/php-fpm.conf)
www-data  114803  0.0  0.3 227764 26744 ?        S    17:10   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
www-data  114804  0.0  0.1 227196  8896 ?        S    17:10   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
www-data  114805  0.0  0.1 227196  8896 ?        S    17:10   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
www-data  114806  0.0  0.1 227196  8896 ?        S    17:10   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
```

What I really don't understand is why when I keep refreshing the individual pages do I sometimes see the 8.0 site showing that it is using php8.1 and vice versa. I sometimes have to refresh the pages 10-20 times before it switches but it never fails to show up sooner rather than later.

How would I go about figuring out why this is happening, or is there something very obvious that I'm missing?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you looked into Apache's or NGINX's enabled modules?  I'd be willing to bet you have 2 versions of PHP enabled ..  Disable the module you wish not to use at the web server level ..

Comment: While this overlaps with PHP programming, I think you'll probably get better help at [sf]

Comment: @Zak I will amend my post, the 2 versions of PHP are wished for, since while this example is just with phpinfo there are actually 2 versions of an application which are running which are producing undesired results due to the exact same process as is happening with phpinfo.

Comment: @Barmar thanks I'll put the question there too.